# Where are navigation elements declared in default Web Forms template?

Tags: c#, asp.net

VERY very basic question. I'm trying to learn ASP.NET. I created a default website1 in VS 2013 Community I get a ton of files. When I run the app in IS, the default.aspx web page appears and all is OK, but above the web page is a banner with links to contact.aspx, login.aspx. register.aspx, etc. and I cannot find where that banner is? It's not on default.aspx. Where is it? Seaching the project for "Contact.aspx" only returns one result, the page itself, as an example.

Comment: This is normal you an create an empty project and add what you need manually if you do not want to use MasterPages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably coming from a [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx). Look at the `<%@ Page %>` header at the tops of the `.aspx` files. You'll see they reference a master page. A Master Page is used to provide structure to the site. It means you don't have to write the same HTML for common elements on every single content page. Content pages (.aspx) then can have their content inserted into the Master Page. And yes, you can nest master pages. This is all done through the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />` (higher level Master Page) and `<asp:Content />` (nested Master Page or Content Page) tags.

Let's look at an example:

MasterPage.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Main" runat="server" />
         </div>
         <div>                
               <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Footer" runat="server" />
         </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content here.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" runat="Server" >
    Footer content here.
</asp:Content>
```

The resulting HTML will look like this on the client when you access Default.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ContentPage_form1">
     <div>
          Main content here.
     </div>
     <div>
          Footer content here.
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Take special note of how the ID of the form changed from the server side to the client. This trips a lot of people up when they start doing client side JavaScript. If you want the ID to not change, you have to add the `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute to the control (you can also set it at page, web.config, or machine.config levels).